# Start test body after jar file loading (from JAVA) is finished

Tags: multithreading, web-services, unit-testing, http, soap

I want to write UNIT test with SOAP webservices. Webservices work in other jar file, which I try to load Runtime.getRuntime().exec(// java - jar ...). Loading jar file takes 2 min. When loading is in new Thread the test ends before loading jar file will be finished. If loading is in main thread, test is not finished. I try to listen HTTP response with while cycle, but when cycle is working, the jar file is not loading.

```
@Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        // Get path of jar file

        thread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(path-to-java.exe -jar webservices.jar);

                    process.waitFor();

                    process.destroy();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        thread.start();

        int responseCode;
        do {
            responseCode = getResponseCodeHTTP("http://localhost:8080/services");
        } while (responseCode < 200 || responseCode >= 400);

        System.out.println("Web services have loaded");
    }

        public int getResponseCodeHTTP(String urlToRead) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(urlToRead);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        int result;
        try {
            conn.connect();
            result = conn.getResponseCode();
        } catch (ConnectException e){
            return 500;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the [edit] link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: I really dont understand your question. Carefully describe what you expect to happen, and what actually happens. Beyond that: don't call something a **unit** test when you actually do a full functional test. A unit test does things in isolation. A test that requires the web service to be started and running is NOT a unit test.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I want to write test, which will start the webservices from jar file (loading process takes 1.5 min) and then execute test. To start web services I use  Runtime.getRuntime().exec and to understand that them started I use HTTP response code. When the code [200-400) , it means the ws started OK.

I tried to debug code inside new Thread and added code with InputStreamReader and while cycle.

```
String line;
InputStream stdout = process.getInputStream();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stdout));
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    System.out.println("[Stdout] " + line);
```

And test successfully executed. The when I removed the while cycle with readline, the problem had repeated.
I have not understand yet why it worked.